# Style for naming a function that is setting an argument by reference?

Tags: c++, coding-style, naming-conventions

So pretend I'm developing a car class and I want one of the car class's functions to return a list of passengers, except I'd like to put a list reference as an argument and just set that list instead of returning a list.

```
void GetPassengerList(PassengerList &passengerList); //sets the list
```

I don't know if I should call it GetPassengerList or SetPassengerList, or something else. I feel like using the words get / set make it seem like there is a private variable that is being manipulated like the typical getter / setter methods. What's a good naming convention to use here?

Comment: Read about return value optimizations

Comment: I wouldn't have such a function, I would prefer to return the list and use RVO so the variable could be `const` (among other reasons) `PassengerList GetPassengerList();`

Comment: What about 'ExportPassengerList'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In our team for input/output arguments we either use

```
void AdjustPassengerList(PassengerList&);
```

or

```
void AddPassengersTo(PassengerList&);
```

Depending on the use-case. For example the first one could be used if you want a list created from more than one car. The second usually reads well in code, something like:

```
car.AddPassengersTo(list);
```